# Why is my Ubuntu VM not installing updates

Tags: apt, package-management, official-repositories

There are are old CVEs which Ubuntu has a fix for.

For example : https://ubuntu.com/security/cve-2019-18276

I currently have Bash version 4.4.20.

If I run apt list --upgradable, I don't see Bash in the list of upgradable packages.

1. Why Bash doesn't show up on the list ? Is it part of other packages ?
2. I have multiple Repos on my sources.list. Does Ubuntu check all of them ?

Thank You

[image]

Comment: Did you read at the bottom of that page?  "This issue appears to only affect bash when bash is setuid. Ubuntu does not ship with bash setuid, so this has minimal impact for Ubuntu users. This is why we have rated the priority for this issue 'low'. reproducer steps in the suse bugzilla"

Comment: At the top of that page, too: "`Status: Needed`." You are looking for patched version of a package *that has not been patched*. Also, Bash 4.4.20 is not in the Ubuntu repositories, which suggests that you are not running a supported release of Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: I am running  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) which the CVE lists as needing the patch and my understanding is that it is a supported release, so I am not following.

Comment: It says `Status: Needed` which means that it is not patched.  But since Canonical does not ship Ubuntu with bash setuid the urgency for them to patch it is very low.  When you see this, chances are they may never patch it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. So from a security perspective, I would love to get some recommendations to deal with this vulnerabilities that are being reported by our Defender for Linux agent.  CVE-2021-3770, CVE-2017-11164 to name a few. Should I ignore these if the patch is not available on the Ubuntu Repo or use another repo to fix these ?